# Customizing button text appearance

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, button

I am working on a vb.net winform application.
By default the text on a button starts after a little space. I need to start the text from the border itself without any space. And also i want to control the spacing by adding some indentation value.

But there are no button properties to control this. Can you please suggest some ways to achieve this. Below is the image to demonstrate the requirement.

[image]

Button 1 represents how the text appears by default. And Button 2 is the output to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to handle Paint event of button to draw string on Button.

Like:

```
Private Sub Button1_Paint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Button1.Paint
        Button1.Text = String.Empty
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Test", Button1.Font, Brushes.Black, New Point(0, 5))
End Sub
```

And Set FlatStyle, BorderColor, BorderSize Properties:

[image]

Output of Button UI:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fot that kind of customization, you will need to create a custom winforms control.

Check this CP article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4871/Divider-Panel-A-tutorial-on-creating-a-custom-Wind

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use image instead of using text. Set image as buttons background image or simple button image and then you can move text to any corner by using alignment property.

Comment: I need to use text as there will be more than 1000 buttons all together and it won't be ideal to have as many background images with text. Also, for change in fonts we'll have to replace images. Not a good idea.

Comment: Please have a loot at this article. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: That is wpf button control :(

Answer (score -1):

there is no need to drive your own class there is a property on Button class in C# and VB both..

[image]

VB

```
Me.Button2.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
```

C#

```
this.button1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
```

Happy Coding and Sharing .. :)

Comment: @Harsh

if its working, accept the answer so that other people can find its useful when they need..

Comment: I think the OP already know this... but if you read carefully the question you will see that this didn't solve the question as there is a space between the border and the text.

Comment: thn he need to create his own button class. either by using the image icon in button at the place of text or create custom button using the existing class..

Comment: Yes @SysDragon. This doesn't solve the problem. There is still a space between the border and the text. The TextAlign is set to Middle left already.

Comment: Then this answer actually is not useful at all. -1

Comment: I don't understand why are you saying this. What for? Are all your answers not useful? This answer do not add anything new, you should consider deleting it or editing it to give a solution.